# How do I fix the error of not finding MSBuild?

Tags: javascript, windows, react-native, msbuild

By referring to the contents of the following link, I made the app made with the existing React Native project run on Windows.

[Links to referenced websites](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/getting-started)

I did this and tried to build with the following command:

> npx react-native run-windows

But when I do this I get the following error:

> ‼ No public VS release found
>
> i Trying pre-release VS
>
> × Could not find MSBuild with VCTools for Visual Studio 16.7 or later. Make sure all required components have been installed
> Command failed. Re-run the command with --logging for more information.

So I found 3 ways to solve this problem by searching.

> 1.Install the Visual Studio build tool
>
> 2. Resetting the MSBuild Path
>
> 3.Install the Visual C++ tool

I tried the first and second methods, but I keep getting the same error.

For the third method, the computer did not have enough storage space to try.

And my development environment is as follows.

Windows 11(22H2)

Visual studio Community 2022(17.5.3)

Visual studio Build Tools 2022(17.5.3)

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.71.5

Is there a good way to solve this problem?If you have, please leave an answer.

Comment: You don't need 'Visual studio Build Tools 2022' with 'Visual studio Community 2022'. 'Build Tools' is subset for situations where the UI is not needed (such as a build machine). Assuming you are using the VS IDE, you can recover some space by uninstalling 'Build Tools'.

Comment: Did you try running the command from the VS Developer Command Prompt? (should be available through windows menu)

Comment: Open the 'Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022' shortcut from the Start menu. Run your command in the resulting console.

Comment: Thanks, the error is solved.